# How to view undelivered mails in Railo server?

Tags: email, railo, lucee

How can I view undelivered mails in railo server? Does it have any undelivered mail folder in server admin?

1. smtp server name and password are provided properly.
2. And my network connection is also good.

But I cant see the undelivered mail in ralio server side (admin).

Comment: Dunno why someone anonymously flagged this to close as "too many possible answers". There's only one/two answer(s). If you're gonna flag a question to be closed, at least explain WHY.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should be able to see them in the Web Admin (not the Server Admin) in the "Tasks" section. Took me a while to find that!

These entries seem to represent files in the WEB-INF\railo\remote-client\open dir, although those files are even less human-readable than their equivalents on ColdFusion.

Comment: One bonus however is that you can see the log of send attempts, how many attempts have been made and the reason for the failure to deliver without having to go digging through another log.

Answer (score 0):

The .tsk files can be opened with LoadObject(). You can get at the subject, body etc. and also see how many times the spooler has tried the send. With a bit of work, these give you more flexibility than the Adobe CF equivalent, IMHO